# back button is clicked and previous view loaded (UINavigationController)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

My app has 2 table view, Tablview A leads to Tableview B. When i change something in TableView B and press back button i got to make a change in tableview A. How o find out that a view is just poped from a stack and displayed ? is ther any delegate which shows this message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     // Redisplay the data.
     [tableView reloadData];
}
```

This will invoke each time the TableViewA appear.
//Pass  object to TableViewB when you push it from TableViewA.